# Error trying to SET a field when two fields in different tables match

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set catid to 584 whenever the rows in the tables ykz2d_crmery_deals and ykz2d_maps_integration have the same company id using the following query:

```
UPDATE ykz2d_maps_integration 
SET catid = '584' 
WHERE ykz2d_crmery_deals.company_id = ykz2d_maps_integration.company_id
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Failed to execute SQL : SQL UPDATE ykz2d_maps_integration SET catid = '584' WHERE ykz2d_crmery_deals.company_id = ykz2d_maps_integration.company_id failed : Unknown column 'ykz2d_crmery_deals.company_id' in 'where clause'
>
> The column company_id does exist within ykz2d_crmery_deals.

What I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE ykz2d_maps_integration , ykz2d_crmery_deals
SET catid = '584' 
where ykz2d_crmery_deals.company_id = ykz2d_maps_integration.company_id
;
```

The table must be listed in the update clause to avoi the error message

Answer (score 0):

I messed around and eventually this worked:

```
UPDATE ykz2d_maps_integration
SET catid='584' 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT company_id
  FROM ykz2d_crmery_deals
  WHERE ykz2d_maps_integration.company_id = ykz2d_crmery_deals.company_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work better and faster:

```
UPDATE ykz2d_maps_integration as ymi
join ykz2d_crmery_deals as ycd on (ycd.company_id=ymi.company_id)
SET ymi.catid='584';
```

It sets `ykz2d_maps_integration.catid='584'` without any subquery syntax.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think tha is MsSql Syntax. For mysql you need: `UPDATE ykz2d_maps_integration as ymi
join ykz2d_crmery_deals as ycd on (ycd.company_id=ymi.company_id)
SET ymi.catid='584' 
;`